# What is the fastest way to check for duplicates in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, azure-sql-database

I have a table that is storing strings in a SQL Azure table. The user can upload files of new strings from a web browser, and I am checking for duplicates based on the Entity Framework context.  My code to add the de-duplicated strings to the context looks like this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(theStream))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!context.MyEntity.Any(o => o.String == line))
        {
            theString = new DAL.TheString();
            theString .String = line;
            context.MyEntity.Add(theString );
            totalAdded++;
        }
    }
}
```

Using MyEntity.Any() is way, way too slow. Handling 20,000 strings takes 40 minutes, and some simple orchestration seems to point to the duplicate check.

My question is: what is the fastest way to do this within EF? Is L2E not the best tool for the job here? Should I get rid of EF altogether? Or should I just queue up the files and set up a background worker, 'cause this is ALWAYS going to be slow.

Comment: Have you hooked up SQL Profiler to confirm that an EXISTS() query is being sent to the DB? Is the String column indexed to support those queries?

Comment: In NHibernate there is an object cache maintained by the "context". If I were doing this in NH, I'd either disable that cache or evict each object after adding it. Otherwise, the context would hold on to those 20k object refs and that can really slow down iterative processing like this. Does EF have a similar caching strategy?

Comment: @SethPetry-Johnson How could it not be being sent to the DB?  Of course it is.  And it doesn't matter how efficient it is through the use of an index.  Executing even the fastest of DB queries **20,000** times is going to be expensive.

Comment: @Servy - if the predicate won't translate to T-SQL it may pull back all the objects and then test in memory. Don't think that's the prob, but it only takes a second to confirm.  Indexing makes a big difference; 20k PK lookups in 40 minutes is very possible. 

Point is, these are the first troubleshooting steps I identified to get more information about the problem.  DO you have anything constructive to add?

Comment: @SethPetry-Johnson As I said before, this *is* going to ping the database every time.  It's the way EF is built.  I don't need to test anything to know that.  Yes, an index would help, I'm not saying it wouldn't.  I'm saying that *it doesn't do nearly enough*.  Even *with* an index performing 20,000 indexed queries is going to take a *very* long time.  You need to avoid performing so many queries entirely, not make them more efficient.

Comment: @SethPetry-Johnson The predicate is well defined in T-SQL. One point to add is the query is against SQL-Azure. Depending on where the query is originating, the network latency itself might add some overhead.

Comment: Whats the sql datatype on the "string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your database table isn't so large that the strings cannot all fit into memory, you can put them into a `HashSet` through one query and then query against that in-memory collection:

```
var lines = new HashSet<string>(context.MyEntity.Select(o => o.Property));
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(theStream))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        if (lines.Add(line))
        {
            //add line
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't have enough memory for this to work, then your best bet would likely be to create a new trigger in the database to verify that the property is unique, and that will throw out records that attempt to create duplicates.  Then you can attempt to add all of the lines from your stream and let the DB sort out which ones to keep when it gets them all.

Comment: Don't need a trigger, just make a unique index on the column and trap the duplicate key exception in the loop.

Comment: @SethPetry-Johnson That would depend on the specific type of DB used.  I have no idea what DB he's using and whether it supports such a feature, but by all means use that if it's available to you.  The idea is the same.

Comment: This worked good, thanks. Now I am processor bound on the SaveChanges(). Better problem to have.